# Understanding the logstash retry policy

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have kibana and  elasticsearch instance running on a machine. Logstash and filebeat are running on other machine.

The flow is working perfectly fine. I have one doubt and i need to understand that. I made elasticsearch go down and made logstash to pump some logs to elasticearch. Since elasticsearch is down, i am hoping data will be lost. But when i brought up the elasticsearch service, Kibana was able to show the logs which was sent when elasticsearch was down.

When i googled online, i got to know that logstash retries to connect in elasticsearch is down.

May i please know how to set this parameter

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-retry_initial_interval) implements exponential backoff using two parameters called:

- `retry_initial_interval`
- `retry_max_interval`

If a bulk call fails, Logstash will wait for `retry_initial_interval` seconds and try again. If it still fails, it will wait for `2 * retry_initial_interval` and try again. Ans so on until the wait time reaches `retry_max_interval`, at which point it will keep trying every `retry_max_interval` seconds indefinitely.

Note that this retry policy only works when ES is unreachable. If there's another error, such as a mapping error (HTTP 400) or a conflict (HTTP 409), the bulk call will not be retried.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for the info. These parameters(**retry_initial_interval &  retry_max_interval**)should be set in Logstash or ElasticSearch.

Comment: Obviously in your Logstash configuration. ES has no idea that Logstash is sending document to it in bulk.

Comment: Hi Val, Sorry i was in the middle of something. I am trying to setup x-pack for kibana,elasticsearch and logstash and i am facing issues with that. Anyways i added the retry_initial_interval & retry_max_interval as follows,output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
      user => ["elastic"]
      password => ["changeme"] 
      retry_initial_interval => 5
      retry_max_interval => 50
    }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}  when i started logstash service, i did not see any error. Hope its working fine. i could not test as i am in the middle of x-pack.

Comment: Please let me know if i have added the retry parameters properly in logstash.conf properly.

Comment: wrong , logstash will retry if index is read only as well (and this can cause big trouble)